# Excel Found unreadable content, Do you want to recover contents of this workbook. exporting from RDLC

Tags: asp.net, excel, rdlc

When trying to Export RDLC as EXCEL(xlsx) using ReportViewer from backend,
Excel is throwing
"***Excel Found unreadable content, Do you want to recover contents of this workbook***".
I tried to  rename the file type as zip  and extract the contents and tried to modify xml(just introduced new line after first tag
).
Then followed by Zip and rename to XLSX. which resolved the issue and  excel opened without any message.
How to resolve the issue?
Went through many posts which did not solve the actual cause.

I have even tried with **Blank RDLC Report**. which did not resolve the issue , which shows the issue is not with **Report Data**.  The same is working fine with XLS type.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution:
As per available code online for downloading RDLC Report from backend,Response is handled badly and forgot to end the response which lead to corrupted file and above error.
Just included **Response.End();**  at the end and the issue is resolved.